# Not able to communicate with Pods locally created in AWS EC2 instance with kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, kubernetes, cluster-computing

I have created simple nginx deplopyment in Ubuntu EC2 instance and exposed to port through service in kubernetes cluster, but I am unable to ping the pods even in local envirnoment. My Pods are running fine and service is also created successfully. I am sharing some outputs of commands below

kubectl get nodes

```
NAME               STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
ip-172-31-39-226   Ready    <none>   2d19h   v1.16.1
master-node        Ready    master   2d20h   v1.16.1
```

kubectl get po  -o wide

```
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP              NODE               NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
nginx-deployment-54f57cf6bf-dqt5v   1/1     Running   0          101m   192.168.39.17   ip-172-31-39-226   <none>           <none>
nginx-deployment-54f57cf6bf-gh4fz   1/1     Running   0          101m   192.168.39.16   ip-172-31-39-226   <none>           <none>
sample-nginx-857ffdb4f4-2rcvt       1/1     Running   0          20m    192.168.39.18   ip-172-31-39-226   <none>           <none>
sample-nginx-857ffdb4f4-tjh82       1/1     Running   0          20m    192.168.39.19   ip-172-31-39-226   <none>           <none>
```

kubectl get svc

```
NAME               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes         ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP        2d20h
nginx-deployment   NodePort       10.101.133.21   <none>        80:31165/TCP   50m
sample-nginx       LoadBalancer   10.100.77.31    <pending>     80:31854/TCP   19m
```

kubectl describe deployment nginx-deployment

```
Name:                   nginx-deployment
Namespace:              default
CreationTimestamp:      Mon, 14 Oct 2019 06:28:13 +0000
Labels:                 <none>
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
                        kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                          {"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"Deployment","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"nginx-deployment","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"replica...
Selector:               app=nginx
Replicas:               2 desired | 2 updated | 2 total | 2 available | 0 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:  app=nginx
  Containers:
   nginx:
    Image:        nginx:1.7.9
    Port:         80/TCP
    Host Port:    0/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
  Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   nginx-deployment-54f57cf6bf (2/2 replicas created)
Events:          <none>
```

Now I am unable to ping 192.168.39.17/16/18/19 from master, also not able to access curl 172.31.39.226:31165/31854 from master as well.   Any help will be highly appreciated..

Comment: What is the response of curl?  Also, can you post logs of each pod? .Also as per the node naming policy the IP in the node name and the one you are using is most likely the private IP of your worker instance.

Comment: Thanks for reply. the output is 
curl 172.31.39.226@31165
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server

If I cant access the private Ip in local cluster. how can I access it externally.

Comment: @damitj07 at master

Comment: So master will not be able to curl the private IP of worker node. That is not how this works.

Comment: I can able to ping the private IP of worker through master. also I have tried it using public IP.

 curl https://52.201.242.84@31854
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server

still the output is same

Comment: @damitj07  Actually I am newbie in kubernetes, I will appreciate if you help me. I have added logs of pods in above question

Comment: ok I tried to reach this URL https://52.201.242.84:31165. I think you need to whitelist this port for public access or the IP. This can be done via security group for the worker node EC2

Comment: You are a champ, Now I am getting the desired output on http://52.201.242.84:31854/ . But I have two service one I have created it with nodeport and other with type LoadBalancer. I can able to access with the one with LoadBalancer but not with Nodeport. Though I have allowed both these ports in security groups.

Comment: ok 1 step at a time buddy. Load Balancing is a bit tricky. I think we will get there soon enuf.

Comment: Let add an answer . So we can carry on discussion on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the information, you have provided. And from the discussion we had the worker node has the Nginx pod running. And you have attached a NodePort Service and Load balancer Service to it.

The only thing which is missing here is the server from which you are trying to access this.

So, I tried to reach this URL `52.201.242.84:31165`. I think all you need to do is whitelist this port for public access or the IP. This can be done via security group for the worker node EC2.

Now the URL above is constructed from the public IP of the worker node plus(+) the **NodePort** svc which is attached. Thus here is a simple formula you can use to get the exact address of the pod running.

```
Pod Access URL = Public IP of Worker Node + The NodePort
```